# LX08H whit chip CH341 only receive when buffer contains 32 bytes

Tags: rs485

My problem is that when I use serial in LX08H, I only read data when 32 bytes have been sent, if more than 32 are sent, only the first 32 are received and the rest are left in some buffer until 32 bytes are completed. How can I receive bytes one at a time?

Comment: I have stumbled on the same problem. LW08H uses CH341T chip instead of more common CH340G. In the Linux driver code I can see a comment "CH341A buffers data until a full endpoint-size packet (32 bytes) has been received unless bit 7 is set." appearently this does not work or both yours and mine kernel drivers are too old. https://github.com/torvalds/linux/tree/master/drivers/usb/serial

Comment: In my case it was solved updating the kernel of my distribution, it seems that the error came from a "flag" that had to be deactivated, this flag controls the buffer of 32 bytes